# Azure Function and permanent process

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I need to update data from external resource and should do it as often as possible.

I created Azure Function with 1-minute timer and marked it as `Singleton`:

```
    [Singleton]
    [FunctionName("FunctionSync")]
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    }
```

but, seems to me, it's being created queue with waiting instances, so it's not good.

Other way - add queue with one message like semaphore and get message on the start add message on the end of function:

```
    [Singleton]
    [FunctionName("FunctionSync")]
    public async Task Run(
        [QueueTrigger("tablet-management-sync-last-datetime", Connection = "StorageConnectionString")]string myQueueItem,
        [Queue("tablet-management-sync-last-datetime", Connection = "StorageConnectionString")]CloudQueue outputQueue,
        ILogger log
        )
    {
```

but this solution is fragile, if something wrong, message is not added to queue and process is stopped.

Which solution is the best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Functions that are triggered via a TimerTrigger will [only be called once per interval](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#scale-out), even if there are multiple instances. So this is something that you don't have to worry about. It does this using Blob Leases, and you can [read about it here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/TimerTrigger#singleton-locks) on the webjob sdk wiki.